# What is the difference between “I am not agree” and “I do not agree”?

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between "I am not agree" and "I do not agree"?

1. Question: "I am not agree with your opinion." 
   Explanation: The grammar is not okay because "agree" is a verb.
   We can use the adjective "agreed" to "I am not agreed with your opinion." (Correct or not? If not, why not?)
2. Question: "I do not agree with your opinion."
   Explanation: We use "do" in question and negative sentences.
   So, the "negative" sentence needs to add "do". (Correct or not? If not, why not?)

[REFERENCE](https://forum.english.best/t/am-vs-do-i-am-not-agree-vs-i-dont-agree/22570/6)

Comment: where do you have that "agreed" is an adjective? That just seems like a past-tense verb to me.

Comment: @katatahito that is why I need  someone to help me [Ref](https://forum.english.best/t/am-vs-do-i-am-not-agree-vs-i-dont-agree/22570/6)

Comment: You can't say *I am not agreed*. *Agreed* is the past tense of the verb *agree*. Instead, you would say *I am not* [***in agreement***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20agreement). I'm not entirely sure where that leaves your question, however.

Comment: @JasonBassford thanks for your command it is from [URL](https://forum.english.best/t/am-vs-do-i-am-not-agree-vs-i-dont-agree/22570/6)

Comment: @willie Following that link, it's talking about *agreeable*, which is something quite different. (But I will note that the person there reached the same conclusion I did in my initial comment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, *I am not agree* is ungrammatical, because *am* cannot be followed by a verb in the base (or infinitive form).

*I am agreed* is grammatical, but fails semantically.

Grammatically it could be the past participle of the verb *agree*, in which case *I am agreed* could be a passive: but people can't be the object of agreement, so it doesn't make sense. With a different subject, this is fine: for example, *The sale is agreed.*

Alternatively, *agreed* can be an adjective. But this is only used of a group where all the members are in agreement with each other about something: it is not normally used of an individual who is in agreement with somebody else. So *we are agreed* is fine, but *I am agreed* is odd.

As simple verbs, *I agree* and I do not agree_ are grammatical and normal. As you say, nearly all verbs require the helper *do* to form the negative.

Comment: If "I am agreed" is passive, then the active counterpart should be "They agreed me". Is that grammatical? The passive should be, although odd, "I am agreed with".

Comment: Yes, @user178049, I think it is grammatical, but nonsense. "The sale was agreed" is certainly grammatical, so it's hard to see why "I am agreed" should not be.

Comment: Ok, I see; according to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/agree), "agree + something" is common in the UK. I'm not used to BrE.

Comment: Ah. I wasn't aware that _agree_ isn't used that way elsewhere.